# fread struct with vector from binary file gives Access violation reading error

Tags: c++, fread, access-violation

I'm trying to read and write a struct with vectors to a file in C++. I'm getting read violation error, why is that and how can I fix it? Here's the code.

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct A
{
    vector<int> int_vector;
};

int main()
{
    A a1 = A();

    a1.int_vector.push_back(3);


    FILE* outfile = fopen("save.dat", "w");
    if (outfile == NULL)
    {
        cout << "error opening file for writing " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    fwrite(&a1, sizeof(A), 1, outfile);
    fclose(outfile);



    struct A ret;
    FILE* infile;
    infile = fopen("save.dat", "r");
    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        cout << "error opening file for reading " << endl;
        return 1;

    }
    while (fread(&ret, sizeof(A), 1, infile))
    {

    }
    fclose(infile);
    cout << ret.int_vector.at(0) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

As a side note: If I change the struct A to

```
struct A
{
    int int_vector;
};
```

the program works as expected without errors, so there's something about the vector which is causing the problem.

Comment: you can't directly read/write to objects that contain pointers

Comment: You need to serialize your data. The actual vector object contains no data at all, just a couple of pointers and such.

Comment: `fwrite(&a1, sizeof(A), 1, outfile);` -- Amazing how so many new programmers believe that this will work correctly for any `A` type -- StackOverflow is littered with the same question.  It's as if this erroneous way of writing data comes from a book that many seem to be using.

Comment: The simple reason why this could never work is that `sizeof(A)` is the same value (maybe it is 64, whatever), whether there are no items in the vector, or a million items in the vector.  So you are telling `fwrite` to always write `sizeof(A)` bytes of data.  So how will this magically write potentially millions of bytes of data if you're only telling `fwrite` to write `sizeof(A)` data?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yeah you're right. In my case it was just naivety and wishful thinking I guess. The error was pretty cryptic so I wasn't sure whether this was possible to do or not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could it potentially work with arrays instead of vectors? Since arrays have a fixed length.

Comment: @HåkanTroberg -- In general -- `#include <type_traits> ... if (std::is_trivially_copyable<A>())` -- if that `if` statement yields `false`, then you can't use `A` in the way you're using it.  In addition, if `A` contains pointers, then it can't be used in the way you're using it, unless for some strange reason you are actually trying to write pointer values.

Comment: @HåkanTroberg I think it would work with std::array, never tried it before though, if not just use normal c array

Comment: @HåkanTroberg -- that depends on what's in the array.

Comment: @HåkanTroberg -- [See this](https://godbolt.org/z/Prbf7qr8v).  Take that code, and add/remove/change items in those structs to see the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::vector` as you know, is dynamic, it simply contains a pointer to the data located on the heap. The sizeof(std::vector) is a constant value, you could not just write it to a file then read it back for that reason.

What you need is serialization, there are some awesome open source library that you could find on github which will solve your problem.